# codeigniter session doesn't work in my desktop

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'm making website using web framework that is codeigniter.
When i use session, It doesn't work. So i visit codeigniter forum that is also made up of codeigniter. Then i login that site. But same problem is happened. Session is not maintained.(Both chrome and explorer).
How should i do to solve this problem??
Here is my code.(But i think there are no error.)

```
    $dd = $this->db->get_where('acc_wait_tb', array('id'=>$this->input->post('id')))->row();
    $new_data = array(
      'user_id'=>$dd->id,
      'name'=>$dd->name,
      'email'=>$dd->email,
    $this->session->set_userdata($new_data);
```

(In the user_data column that is in ci_sessions table have all data that i stored. But when i call this at web using all_userdata() function, there is no data stored.)

**Session settings (application/config/config.php)**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Comment: Could you show all the config items from **application/config/config.php** that start with `$config['sess_`

Comment: yes! here is that code.
$config['sess_cookie_name']   = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']    = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']    = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

Comment: Check that the `user_agent` column is long enough in your database.

Comment: Dp you have load session library? Please check your sql result `var_dump($dd)` and check session is work `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata())` before you set session. And then check `$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";` on your `config.php` file

Comment: yes, i have load session library using autoload.

Comment: And Column is enough to store the data.

Comment: i can log in my web site normally... But i couldn't in my desktop.

Comment: @오현준 so the problem is in your localhost? maybe is a problem with your local config. Or even a cache problem. I mean, the code works online but no offline: the problem shouldnt be the code

Comment: @oPi Thank you for comment! My web is activated at virtual server, not local.When i checked other computer(window7 or 8), that problem is also happened, But at the mac ox and mobile, i can login normally. I don't know what is wrong still now...

Comment: @오현준 no problem. Did you checked the security configuration of the win7-8 environment? i mean, if its fails, it fails always. It has no sense that it only fails under that environment

Comment: @oPi Oh... Thank you so much! Can i ask one more question?? What setting should i check in window?

Comment: @오현준 start watching if youre accepting cookies. Also clear the cache, ...